# Flutter: Uniform container size regardless of the platform (android, iOS)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

Example for the structure of the page:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 2),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _block1(),
                    _block2(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 4),
                child: _block3(),
              )
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 4),
                child: _block4(),
              )
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 4),
                child: _block5(),
              )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Example of one of the small container widgets to be loaded

```
  Widget _block1() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'headline',
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 12,
            ),
            Text(
              'text',
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 4,
            ),
            Text(
              'text',
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 4,
            ),
            Text(
              'text',
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 4,
            ),
            Text(
              'text',
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 4,
            ),
            Text(
              'text',
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 4,
            ),
            Text(
              'text',
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 4,
            ),
            Text(
              'text',
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 4,
            ),
            Text(
              'text',
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Example of one of the large container:

```
  Widget _block3() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
        Text(
        'another container for displaying different contents',
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),),
      ])
    );
  }
```

[Android tablet Nexus 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fHoK.png)

but on iOS iPad I get overflowed errors

[iOS iPad 8th generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjrrR.png)

Is there a way to adjust the height and width of the containers so that they look the same on Android and iOS and do not cause overflowed errors without the aid of "SingleChildScrollView"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap each text in the _bloc1 widget with Expanded and remove the SizeBox widgets. Example, for the individual fixed SizedBox heights in your _block1 widget, they will eventually add up and cause overflow error when the total size becomes larger than available space. Also note that if your widgets are too many, things will still overflow.

Another possible solution is using [FittedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) to resize your texts or contents based on available width and height.

Comment: Thank you, the solution you suggested works very well on both Android and iOS